# REGEX: Match at the beginning of a string OPTIONALLY

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Im building a regex to match the word combo `W7`. Not `W73` or `NW7` or `2W7`.

So far I have

```
^w7{1}\b
```

which works perfectly.   However, I have a problem.

I also need to have `//W7` (with 2 forward slashs) also match.  So if `W7` or `//W7` are entered they should match

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an optional `//` at the start.

```
^(//)?w7\b
```

You may need to escape them.

```
^(\/\/)?w7\b
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just add an [optional](http://php.net/regexp.reference.repetition) [group](http://php.net/regexp.reference.subpatterns) to your regex

```
^(?://)?W7\b
```

Remember to use a non-`/` [delimiter](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) (it's tidier than escaping those slashes).

If you want the subject string to only ever contain `//W7` or `W7` then an alternative (full pattern) would be:

```
~^(?://)?W7$~D
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `^(//)?W7`? the question mark indicates *one or zero occurrences*.